# EOFError (end of file reached) in Ruby on Rails with http.request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, get

I am trying to get json form url :

```
uri = URI.parse("http://84.38.185.251:9262/send")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

response.code             # => 301
response.body             # => The body (HTML, XML, blob, whatever)
response["cache-control"] # => public, max-age=2592000
puts response.body
```

but i get an error :`EOFError (end of file reached):
  app/controllers/sensors_controller.rb:35:in sensinfo'

sensors_controller.rb:35:

```
response = http.request(request)
```

What am i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a some sort of bug; [`typhoeus`](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) seems to work:

```
require 'typhoeus'

response = Typhoeus.get("http://84.38.185.251:9262/send")
p response.body
#=> {"ids":"-1","data":{"temp":"nan","h":"-1"},"status":"255","voltage":"-1"}
```

Comment: Does it need to require other gems?  it give me an error `require': No such file to load -- typhoeus (LoadError)  but i included it to gem list and made bundle install

Comment: No it doesn't, it should work just fine with `gem 'typhoeus'` inside the `Gemfile`

Comment: I simply rebooted the server)

Answer (score 18):

this error mostly get for using https

If it is `https` then

Please try this one

```
uri = URI.parse("https://84.38.185.251:9262/send")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
http.use_ssl = true  
response = http.request(request)
```

Note aditional

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

If it is not `https`

```
http.use_ssl = false
```

or you can add the condition

```
http.use_ssl = true if domain =~ /^https/
```

you can get more on this https://web.archive.org/web/20140226183826/http://expressica.com/2012/02/10/eoferror-end-of-file-reached-issue-when-post-a-form-with-nethttp/

Comment: I have http.use_ssl set to true and an explicit 'https://' (See for yourself--my code is at https://github.com/betesh/social_count/blob/v0.0.7/lib/social_count/twitter_user.rb) but still saw this error once, with a stacktrace ending at `openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `sysread_nonblock'` called from `http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri))`.  I suspect that sometimes the connection abruptly terminates due to hardware/power failures so there's never a 100% guarantee that this won't happen.  But that's just a guess.